# JavaScript loaded external content SEO

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo

I wonder what is the best way to have JavaScript loaded content indexed by search engines. I know that search engines don't execute JavaScript, but i am thinking more of an progressive enchantment.
I am creating a responsive website, and on the home page i will have some sections about most visited products and recommended product that i plan to load depending on the device detected. These products will be in sliders with thumbnail images and names of the products.
If mobile is detected slider content will not load, ant the link to the external page will be shown.
I know that external content will be indexed via link to those resources.
Where will the users be directed from search in this case? To the external page or home page?
Will it be bad for SEO if i show only product names on front page so they can be indexed and hide them with css?
What is the best way to index that content and possibly direct users from search to home page.

Also, i've seen the Ajax crawling http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/ but i would like not to use that if there is any better way.

Comment: try webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not try tricks like hiding content with css. Crawlers are getting smart about things like these, to prevent people from stuff hidden keywords into their pages.
2. I also don't like the ajaxcrawling solution google presents, it might be usefull for some very specific cases, but I would avoid that.
3. For your responsive page, focus on the data you want all users to see, and all bots to see. This data should be present on the page, when it loads. It should be visible and ideally should have proper semantic weight. Like H1, H2 etc. This basically means that links to other pages of your site (header / footer navigation links) should be available on the page.
4. For responsiveness, the alignment of sections of your page will happen based on the device and media queries.
5. From a progressive enhancement perspective, if based on the real estate and capability of the browser, you decide to show some more content in a particular section, be aware that this content will be unavailable to crawlers. So it would not be indexed.
6. If crawlers can only see links to other pages on the home page, you do not lose anything. The link's alt and href content will be pulled up while indexing your home page, and if a search query matches the content, users will be presented with the link to the secondary page. (Which is what you want anyways.)

Hope this helps.

If there is a specific part of your question that remains unanswered, please leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer.